# How to get value of dynamic input in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a dynamic header with a dynamic hidden input from php by doing an ajax request. The input gets created fine. The problem is not there. Below the same page I'm using plain javascript to get the value of that dynamic input. The Ajax and the javascript are two different codes. If they were not, I would simply load from ajax success but I can't do this here.

Problem is, in the console I get this error :

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

**How can I fix this?**

hidden input

```
<input id="appStatus" type="hidden" value="0">
```

javascript

```
window.onload = function() {

 var app_mode = document.getElementById('appStatus').value;

    if (app_mode === 0) {//dev

        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxx');

    } else {//live prod

        var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_xxxx');
    }

};
```

Comment: use promise, or do this on ajax success

Comment: @MisterJojo : I know how to do this on ajax success. The Javascript is a different script. It's for stripe. What is promise? Can you show me please? Thank you

Comment: there is no other way

Comment: @MisterJojo : Sir can you show me promise? I'm unfamiliar with this.

Comment: This might help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249641/enable-disable-events-of-dom-elements-with-js-jquery]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling document.getElementById('appStatus').value before your input field is generated by ajax request.

Use Promise for this

```
  function getInput() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            ...,
            success: function(response) {
                resolve(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                reject();
            }
        });  
      });
    }

window.onload = function() {
getInput().then(response => {
  var app_mode = document.getElementById('appStatus').value;

  if (app_mode === 0) {//dev
     var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxx');
  } else {//live prod
     var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_xxxx');
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes I do know this. I'm looking for a soluton :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `setTimeout` function as `success` function

Add event `DOMNodeInserted`

When new element is inserted in document then function is automatically called

```js
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",function() {
 var app_mode = document.getElementById('appStatus');
 if(!app_mode) return;
 console.log(app_mode.value);
});
setTimeout(()=>{
 document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = '<input id="appStatus" type="text" value="0">';
},3000);
```

```html
<div></div>
```